# Free Reports system like Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report

We are building an system which is B/S structure.And  the customer want to print the reports of their sells data.But they want to use an free report to do this!
I wander what's the better free report system to use?
Ps:We use asp.net!
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a link to a comparison of three open-source reporting solutions (BIRT, Pentaho and Jasper):
http://www.innoventsolutions.com/birt-jasper-pentaho-comparison-matrix.html

I don't know how well these solutions integrate with asp.net, but they are probably the best-established open source solutions.

Answer (score 1):

How about just MS Excel? It's not free, but your client probably already has it.  And if they don't, OpenOffice.org can open it for them.

Excel is versatile and can import/export data in many ways.  You have graphs, tables, conditional formatting, tabs, controls, and VBA can allow for serious customization. Also, most end-users are already familiar with it, so it will be easier to get accepted by your user community.

The downsides include weak security and ugly charts (but if your client has Office 2010, everything looks much, much better).